# How to disable the dirty check in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

I use hibernate 5, and I want to know how can I disable the dirty check or manually remove elements from stored-snapshot list?
I have

```
class A{
.... 
 @OneToMany
 private List<B> childs;
...
}
```

then I deleted object from child list immediate from DB using JPQL then manually remove the object from the list

```
a.getChilds().remove(b)
```

then when I merged the object a give an exception

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException:Unable to find com.company.package.B with id 156983
```

After debugging I found the deleted object b inside the storedSnapshot list.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me what you would like to do. I will give you a couple options.

If you don't want Hibernate to change anything in you DB unless you specifically flush it, then you can change your FlushMode to manual. You can do that with the following configuration:

```
<property name="org.hibernate.flushMode" value="MANUAL"/>
```

If you don't want that changes in your object to be commited you can simply disattach it:

```
entityManager.detach(myObject);
```

**EDIT** after reading your comments:

I think your problem is more likely to be on your strategy to handle this cached data. I strongly recommend you to don't change your object with information that you might not want to save.

The general idea of using something like Hibernate is to have an Object that represents a row in your database.

What you could do is store this cached information in a different object and only change A when you know for sure that you want this information on the DB.

Comment: @RaiedRaafat You are welcome. I edited my answer. Let me now if that solves your problem.

Comment: But I cache some other values in object 'a' not need to merge on removing the object b and not need to refresh the entity a to preserve these cached data

Comment: @RaiedRaafat So you are putting information on object A, and you don't want this information to be persisted, but you want the deletion of the child to be?

Comment: yes, depending on user decision after delete I may need to merge object A

Comment: @RaiedRaafat I think I got it. I edited my answer again.